# Is there a way to obtain a nested table from an aggregate sql query?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables:

- `post` which has an id and some data fields
- `tags` which has a post id (foreign key on `posts.id`), a key and a value field (there is no id or index, just the tuple)

**Posts**:

```
| id | title | body |
+----+-------+------+
|  1 | t1    | b1   | 
|  2 | t2    | b2   |
```

**Tags**

```
| post | key | value |
+------+-----+-------+
|  1   | bar | baz   |
|  1   | foo | bar   |
```

If I want to retrieve some posts with its own tags a could use a query like

```
select posts.*, tags.*
from posts
left join tags on posts.id = tags.post
```

and I will get

```
| id | title | body | post | key | value |
+----+-------+------+------+-----+-------+
| 1  |    t1 |   b1 |    1 | bar |   baz |
| 1  |    t1 |   b1 |    1 | foo |   bar |
| 2  |    t2 |   b2 |      |     |       |
```

But I wanted to obtain a single row for post, so I have grouped the query by Id and `group_concat` the tag's data in a json fashion with this query

(notice that I'm making this experiment on an SQLite database and the `||` is the operator for string concatenation)

```
select 
    posts.*, 
    "{" || group_concat('"' || tags.key || '": "' || tags.value || '"') || "}" as tags
from
    posts
left join 
    tags on posts.id = tags.post
group by 
    posts.id
```

And this is the result

```
| id | title | body |                        tags |
+----+-------+------+-----------------------------+
| 1  |    t1 |   b1 | {"bar": "baz","foo": "bar"} |
| 2  |    t2 |   b2 |                             |
```

My question: is there a way to aggregate the tags result in a better way? I mean something more similar to a normal SQL table, maybe something that does not need to be parsed after (or even something queryable).

I would like to get a table inside the *tags* cells, something like this

```
| id | title | body |        tags |
|    |       |      | key | value |
+----+-------+------+-----+-------+
| 1  |    t1 |   b1 | bar |   baz |
|    |       |      +-----+-------+
|    |       |      | foo |   bar |
+----+-------+------+-----+-------+
| 2  |    t2 |   b2 |     |       |
+----+-------+------+-----+-------+
```

Is this achievable in some way (even with a different sql dbms)?

Answer (score 0):

The result of a SQL query is a dataset consisting of rows and columns and there is no concept of table inside table or cell inside cell.
The nearest to your requirement is a query that would return `null`s or blanks after the first row of each group:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN t.id END id,
       CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN t.title END title,
       CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN t.body END body,
       t.post, t.key, t.value
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.id ORDER BY t.key) rn
  FROM posts p LEFT JOIN tags t
  ON t.post = p.id 
) t
ORDER BY t.id, t.rn
```

Results:

| id | title | body | post | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | t1 | b1 | 1 | bar | baz |
| null | null | null | 1 | foo | bar |
| 2 | t2 | b2 | null | null | null |

Or:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN t.id ELSE '' END id,
       CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN t.title ELSE '' END title,
       CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN t.body ELSE '' END body,
       COALESCE(t.post, '') post, 
       COALESCE(t.key,'') key,
       COALESCE(t.value, '') value
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.id ORDER BY t.key) rn
  FROM posts p LEFT JOIN tags t
  ON t.post = p.id 
) t
ORDER BY t.id, t.rn
```

Results:

| id | title | body | post | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | t1 | b1 | 1 | bar | baz |
|  |  | 1 | foo | bar |  |
| 2 | t2 | b2 |  |  |  |

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=4352fe8affd565cb837565ba52544db9).

Comment: I know that the first normal form says that you can't have aggregate data, but I also know that there are DBMS such oracle and PostgreSQL that allows you to have data in the form of nested records (arrays of objects o even nested tables https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_SQL), so it could be interesting to know how to display such data and how to create sql views for them

Comment: @asdru As far as I know Oracle does support nested tables, but PostgreSQL doesn't (arrays are not nested tables) and nested tables are not SQL standard. Also your question is tagged SQLite which for sure does not support nested tables.